# Terminating Process in Windows 10 OS

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, process, window

**Background Information:** I'm developing an Windows 10 app. Within my app, some outputs are displayed onto a window console requiring a new process.

**Code Snippet:**

```
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si;
// CreateProcess is defined in processthreadsapi.h
BOOL newProcess = CreateProcess (
0, pszCmdLine, 0, 0, FALSE, DEBUG_THIS_ONLY_PROCESS, 0, 0, &si, &pi
);
```

In the above code snippet, `pszCmdLine` can be `"cmd.exe /c dir"`, `"cmd.exe /c ipconfig"`, or essentially any Windows terminal cmd.

**Problem:** On the front end, a new `cmd` console is generated and the user is able to terminate it. However, it's kept alive in the background. I've attached snips below:

Before Process Accumulating:

[image]

In the above snip, it shows `"cmd.exe /c dir"` being executed and outputted into a cmd console.

After Processes Accumulates:

[image]

In the above snip, it shows how I launched the same `cmd` 4 times and closed it 3 times (i.e. the counter is "(4)" including the main process).

**Real World Problem:** This is essentially consuming memory and has the ability to degrade performance.

**Initial Curiosity:** Shouldn't the Windows OS handle the killing of this process when the user clicks the "x"?

Has anyone faced a similar issue before?

Comment: Does changing the `DEBUG_THIS_ONLY_PROCESS` flag to default help?

Comment: for what you use `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` ? and you really debug process ?

Comment: Are you closing the process and thread handles that CreateProcess returns in the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure?

Comment: @SaileshD You were correct. The error persisted due to using "DEBUG_THIS_ONLY_PROCESS". Changing it to default (0 or CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Change `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` to `0` **or** `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`.

**My Thoughts:**

I suppose the idea behind `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` is to leave the window handle open for the user to observe the output whereas `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` allocates and frees the memory as needed.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a window handle. The process manager won't fully reap and destroy the Process object until the 'debugger' (your application) detaches, e.g. `DebugActiveProcessStop(pi.dwProcessId)`. Of course since you're not writing a debugger of any sort there's no sense in using this flag.

Comment: As to the console window, FYI, CMD is a shell, not a console or terminal. It uses a console that's hosted by an instance of conhost.exe. The system terminates all processes attached to a console when the console is closed, but it can't completely destroy a process that has an attached debugger.

Comment: Older visual studios had this bug ( I haven't seen this off late in VS 2013 & '17) where the zombie consoles won't die off even after debugging has stopped. This is more likely a bug with VS. If interested, you can raise the same in MSDN forums.

Comment: Thank you guys. I appreciate the feedback and knowledge!